# Media Player with Lock Screen with Custom Widget

Tags: android, android-intent

I had used this [tutorial](http://tutorialsface.blogspot.in/2014/07/music-player-with-notification-and-lock.html) example for creating media player. Everything is working in this app.

But I want to add the custom app widget layout like this:

[image: Layout During lock screen]

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What **exactly** is "this problem"?

Comment: specifics of your problem is what?

Comment: I want to add Rewind, Previous, stop, play, refresh,  next, and forward buttons on lock screen.

Comment: In short I want to add the custom widget in my app. And want to display it programmatically if my music is playing and screen is locked